# Why don't we use sodium bicarbonate to neutralise base spills?

Tags: acid-base, safety

According to this document on lab safety (http://faculty.washington.edu/korshin/Class-486/AEESP-safety-notes.pdf), it says to not use $\ce{NaHCO3}$ to neutralise specifically base spills, stating "Do not use acetic acid or
sodium bicarbonate to clean a base spill. The sodium bicarbonate will not neutralize the spill, and acetic
acid could react strongly with the base."

Could someone explain why sodium bicarbonate won't neutralise a base spill? I have always learnt that it is amphiprotic and therefore can be used to neutralise BOTH acid AND base spills.

Comment: NaOH + NaHCO3 -> Na2CO3 + H2O, with sodium carbonate being still caustic, even if less than NaOH.  For neutralization of residues after water washing, it is adviced 2% NaHCO3 for acids and 2% acetic acid for bases, which are advised to kept handy as stock solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to argue that the currently-accepted answer is incorrect.

As the current accepted answer correctly pointed out, the bicarbonate ion dissociates into a proton and a carbonate ion, and that an equilibrium between the bicarbonate ion and the carbonate and hydrogen ion is established.

However, Sam202's calculation assumes that there is no driving force that would shift the equilibrium towards one side or the other. In the case of an acid/base reaction, this is simply not true. Following from [Le Chatelier's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle), the equilibrium can be shifted to favor the products by removing products as they are formed. In the case of sodium bicarbonate reacting with sodium hydroxide, hydrogen ions formed by the dissociation of bicarbonate are removed by reaction with hydroxide ions to form water, causing the equilibrium to shift to favor greater dissociation of bicarbonate, driving the reaction to completion.

As a sidenote, acid/base titrations assume that the reaction between the acid and base is stoichiometric. If Sam202's answer were correct, titrating a weak acid with a strong base or vice-versa would be impractical.

As to the question at hand, the reaction of sodium bicarbonate with sodium hydroxide would produce water and sodium carbonate as pointed out by commenter Poutnik. While sodium carbonate is a weaker base compared to sodium hydroxide (pKa of sodium carbonate is 10.33 compared to 15.7 for sodium hydroxide, according to Wikipedia) it is still basic (For reference, pKa of ammonia is 9.25, pKa of sodium bicarbonate is 6.3). Thus, the reaction of sodium bicarbonate with sodium hydroxide would still leave a base spill, as Poutnik correctly deduced.

Comment: I would like to ask, for me it appears the current answer attempts to find how much bicarb is needed for the pH to be 7, whereas for the NaOH + NaHCO3 reaction, the salt will be basic, meaning, more bicarb will be needed for a neutral pH than just what is required to complete the reaction, hence the calculation. What are your thoughts on this, what calculations would you make for a neutral pH?

Comment: Upvoted. The pH of a typical baking soda solution is in the neighborhood of 8.3 or 8.4. Adding sodium hydroxide raises the pH: the pH has to be intermediate between that of the baking soda and NaOH. It cannot be 7 unless vast quantities of pH 7 water are used to dilute the baking soda and NaOH to ultra-trace levels.

Comment: @Quippy What Ed said. You won't ever get to pH 7 by adding bicarb to sodium hydroxide, because bicarbonate is itself slightly alkaline.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have a strong basic aqueous solution $B$ that we attempt to neutralize with $\ce{NaHCO3}$ working as an acid $A$.

The source of excess $\ce{OH-}$ ions comes from the base, and since it's strong, we can consider:

$$n_{Bo}=n_{\ce{OH-}}\implies C_{Bo}{V_B}=C_{\ce{OH-}}V_B$$

The source of excess $\ce{H+}$ ions is bicarbonate, but since it's a weak acid, we have to consider the equilibrium:

$$\ce{HCO3-(aq)<=>H+(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq)}$$

The equilibrium expression in terms of moles after mixing both solutions is:

$$K_n=K_a\;(V_A+V_B)=\frac{x^2}{C_{Ao}V_A-x}$$

For complete neutralization to take place, both excess $\ce{H+}$ and excess $\ce{OH-}$ ions need to completely react with each other, so:

$$x=C_{Bo}V_B$$

Substituting above:

$$K_a\;(V_A+V_B)=\frac{(C_{Bo}V_B)^2}{C_{Ao}V_A-C_{Bo}V_B}$$

For simplicity, let's consider equal molar concentrations of both solutions and a volume of $\pu{0.1L}$ for our basic solution that needs neutralizing:

$$C_{Ao}=C_{Bo}=\pu{1mol/L}$$

$$V_B=\pu{0.1L}$$

The acid dissociation constant of bicarbonate at 25°C is approximately:

$$K_a=5.012\times10^{-11}$$

Substituting all values:

$$5.012\times10^{-11}\;(V_A+0.1)=\frac{0.1^2}{V_A-0.1}$$

Solving for $V_A$:

$$V_A=\pu{14125.2L}$$

In other words, bicarbonate is considerably weaker as an acid (about 400 times) than it is as a base, so attempting to neutralize a strong basic solution with it would require an enormous amount.

Comment: Sorry once again but could you explain how you got $K_n=K_a(V_a+V_b)$ thanks :)

Comment: $$K_a=\frac{C_C^c\;C_D^d}{C_A^a}=\frac{\left(\frac{n_C}{V}\right)^c\;\left(\frac{n_D}{V}\right)^d}{\left(\frac{n_A}{V}\right)^a}=\frac{n_C^c\;n_D^d}{n_A^a}\left(\frac{1}{V}\right)^{\Delta n}=\;K_n\left(\frac{1}{V}\right)^{\Delta n}$$

$$\Delta n=1$$

$$V=V_A+V_B$$

Comment: Sorry I am really struggling with the notation, just note I'm still a highschool chemistry student. What is $\Delta n$ and what chemicals are subscript $C, D$ and $A$? Could you perhaps write working as $K_a=\frac{\ce{[H3O^+][NaCO3^-]}}{[\ce{NaHCO3}]}$ or something like that thank you!

Comment: I just represented the reaction: $\ce{HCO3- <=>H+ +CO3^{2-}}$ as: 

$$\ce{A<=>C + D}$$ 

$\Delta n$ is the difference between the sum of product molar coefficients and reactant molar coefficients of the reaction:

$$\Delta n=c+d-a=1+1-1=1$$

Comment: Thanks got it and finally, where does $K_n=\frac{x^2}{C_aoV_a-x}$ come from? What does $x$ represent and how did you derive the expression? (Sorry for all the questions but I feel like it'll be so beneficial for me to understand)

Comment: If you're not familiar with ICE tables for equilibrium problems, you should look it up to fully understand these expressions.

Comment: I am, but I learnt to put it in using concentration values not no. of moles which I assume is what $C_aV_a$ gets you, in other words, why does $[\ce{HCO3^-}]=C_aV_a-x$ not $C_a-x$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141266/discussion-between-sam202-and-quippy).

Comment: It seems to me that your calculation assumes that there is nothing that would cause the equilibrium to shift to one side or the other compared to the native dissociation rate. But wouldn't the reaction of H+ and OH- ions remove the product of the bicarbonate's dissociation and drive the equilibrium for the dissociation of bicarbonate further towards the products as per Le Chatelier's principle?

Comment: Also, acid/base titrations work on the assumption that the reaction between the acid and the base is stoichiometric. If your assertion were true, it would be impossible to do a titration without knowing the pKa value of the substance whose concentration one has to determine.

Comment: The calculation is intended to find what amount of $\ce{H+}$ ions from the source $\ce{HCO3-}$ is required to achieve complete neutralization. $\ce{HCO3-}$ in the presence of excess $\ce{OH-}$ will react as an acid, not a base, since the equilibrium: $\ce{HCO3- + H2O <=> H2CO3 + OH-}$ is heavily favored for reactants according to LC, as opposed to the equilibrium: $\ce{HCO3-  <=> H+ + CO3^{2-}}$, which is favored for products under said conditions.

Comment: As the bicarbonate solution is gradually added to the strong basic solution, the equilibrium shift you're describing is taking place, but the calculation accounts for the entire volume of bicarbonate already being added, since the total volume is $V_A+V_B$, and not $V_A$ plus some fraction of $V_B$.

Comment: Also, acid/base titrations necessarily being stoichiometric is only true for the case of strong acid+strong base. This case involves a very weak acid (bicarbonate), so its pKa needs to be considered.

Comment: "Also, acid/base titrations necessarily being stoichiometric is only true for the case of strong acid+strong base" Not true, titrations with various combinations of weak/strong acid/base are described, including weak acid/weak base (Such as ammonia and acetic acid, and the difference in pKa values between ammonia and acetic acid is less than between sodium hydroxide and sodium bicarbonate).

Comment: Such combinations exist for titrations but not all of them are stoichiometric. Having equimolar amounts of $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{CH3COOH}$ does not result in equimolar amounts of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ in solution.